# Creating function using ascii table

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a function to check if the character is letter,punctuation or number by using ord() and ascii table. My problem is checking whether the ordinal value of the character is in the range of that unit. I tried to use `in range(). I'm noob help me pls.

```
def character(string):
if ord(string) in range(97, 123) or (65, 91):
    string = 'letter'
elif ord(string) in range(48, 58):
    string = 'number'
else:
    string = 'punctuation'
return string

print(character('a'))
print(character('6'))
print(character('!'))
```

the result is just the string 'letter'

Comment: Why not using RegEx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the first if-statement with additional range-call (before it evaluated a populated tuple, which is always "truthy", e.g. always evaluates to true):

```
def character(string):
    if ord(string) in range(97, 123) or ord(string) in range(65, 91):
        string = 'letter'
    elif ord(string) in range(48, 58):
        string = 'number'
    else:
        string = 'punctuation'
    return string


print(character('a'))
print(character('6'))
print(character('!'))
```

Output:

```
letter
number
punctuation
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a missing range call:

```
#                                   ↓here
if ord(string) in range(97, 123) or (65, 91):
```

(65, 91) is a non-empty tuple, so it evaluates as True.
Use

```
if ord(string) in range(97, 123) or ord(string) in range(65, 91):
```

You could also do integer comparising:

```
if 97 <= ord(string) <= 122 or 65 <= ord(string) <= 90:
```